# What value bounds the following population?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I have a list of thousands 3D vectors $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$. These are too many to work with so i want to reduce their number. For that cause, i implemented the following criterion:

If a $j$ exists such that:

- $x_j \le x_i$ **and**
- $y_j \le y_i$ **and**
- $|z_j| \ge |x_i|$

then vector $i$ gets eliminated from the list.

My question now is whether the number of vectors produced by the aforementioned elimination process is bounded or not.

If the number of vectors *surving* is $k$ and the original population $p$, is there an $n$ such that:

$p > n \ge k$ ?

---

*PS: I wrote a program in python for this and managed to reduce the number of vectors significantly. I tried it in a lot of sets and indicatively i got from ~75000 to ~100. In some cases i got more than 200 though (216 to be exact) which seems a bit too many..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ need not be bounded. Consider the following infinite set of vectors. $S=\{\langle x,x,x \rangle \mid x\in\mathbb{Z}, x > 0 \} = \{\langle 1,1,1 \rangle, \langle 2,2,2 \rangle,\langle 3,3,3 \rangle, \dots \}$.

None of the vectors in $S$ may be eliminated by the process you describe. The same holds for any subset of $S$ including finite subsets.

Comment: that was more obvious than I expected it to be ☺. Thanks!

Comment: There might be a more difficult probability question in there along the lines of: If a set of x many vectors which are randomly selected using this given distribution are subject to the following elimination rule (in which you need to explain in what order the $i$ and $j$s are selected for comparison), what is the expected size of the remaining set of vectors when this elimination rule can no longer be applied. 

Since I know little probability theory I couldn't solve such a question, but there might be someone who can.